# Sorting pandas dataframe according to first column

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, alphabetical, columnsorting

I'm trying to sort this dataframe based on the 'ID Name'. How do I get the 'ID Name' values in alphabetical order (while keeping the values' corresponding time stamps and comments)?

```
          ID Name             Time Stamp         Comments
0          W10D12    2015-01-24 16:40:34     RandComment1 
1           W8D13    2015-01-25 11:51:21     RandComment1   
2           W8D15    2015-01-25 11:51:41     RandComment1  
3           W8D22    2015-01-25 11:51:47     RandComment2 
4           W8D23    2015-01-25 11:51:54     RandComment2
5           W8D25    2015-01-25 11:51:59     RandComment2
6           W2D27    2015-01-25 11:52:03     RandComment2
7          W16D12    2015-01-24 16:41:45     RandComment3
8          W10D13    2015-01-25 11:53:06     RandComment4
9           W8D15    2015-01-25 11:53:27     RandComment4
..            ...                    ...              ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.sort('ID Name')` will sort the DataFrame by rows based on 'ID Name'

you could add a new column that is the sorted ID:

```
new_col = df['ID Name'].copy()
new_col.sort()
df['sorted ID'] = new_col
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dataframe [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) functionality, the rest of the columns will follow along:

```
result = df.sort_index(by=['ID Name'], ascending=[True])
```

Comment: .sort_values (.sort_values is deprecated)